# Javascript Quiz scoreing

Tags: javascript

I am making a quiz using Javascript and I am stuck on how I would finish calculating the score. Currently in the console, the the users response is pushed as either true or false to an array called userAnswer. From here I am having trouble figuring out how to calculate how many answers are true and showing the score at the end of the test.

Thank you in advance for any help!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    var allQuestions = [{
        question: 'What was the album of the year?',
        choices: ['to Pimp a Butterfly', '1989', 'Traveller', 'Sound and Color'],
        correctAnswer: '1989'
    }, {
        question: 'Who won best new artist?',
        choices: ['Sam Smith', 'Tori Kelly', 'James Bay', 'Meghan Trainor'],
        correctAnswer: 'Meghan Trainor'
    }, {
        question: 'What was the best dance recording?',
        choices: ['Where Are U Now', 'Go', 'Never Catch Me', 'Runaway (U&I)'],
        correctAnswer: 'Where Are U Now'
    }, {
        question: 'What won the best Country Album?',
        choices: ['Montevallo', 'The Blase', 'Traveller', 'Pain Killer'],
        correctAnswer: 'Traveller'
    }];



    var userAnswers = [];
    function score() {
       userAnswers(true)

    
    }

    //Reference to tags
    var questionTitle = $("#questionTitle");
    var selectionList = $("#selectionList");
    var nextButton = $(".next");

    //Initiating some variables
    var questionNumber = 0;
    var correctAnswer = undefined;
    var userChoice = undefined;

    $(".next").click(function() {
        if (userChoice === allQuestions[questionNumber].correctAnswer) {
            userAnswers.push(true);

            console.log(true);
        } else {
            userAnswers.push(false);
            console.log(false);
        }

        questionNumber++;
        populateQuestion(questionNumber);

        console.log(userAnswers);

    });

    function populateQuestion(qNum) {

        $(questionTitle).empty();
        $(selectionList).empty();


        $(questionTitle).append(allQuestions[qNum].question);

        for (var i = 0; i < allQuestions[qNum].choices.length; i += 1) {
            console.log(i);

            $(selectionList).append("<li>" + allQuestions[qNum].choices[i] + "</li>")
        }


    }

    $("ul").on("click", "li", function() {

        userChoice = $(this).text();

        console.log(userChoice);

    });


    $(questionTitle).append(allQuestions[questionNumber].question);

    for (var i = 0; i < allQuestions[questionNumber].choices.length; i += 1) {
        console.log(i);

        $(selectionList).append("<li>" + allQuestions[questionNumber].choices[i] + "</li>")
    }






});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <TITLE>2016 Grammy Quiz</TITLE>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,900,900italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
   <div id = 'container'>
   <h1> 2016 Grammy Quiz</h1> 

        <h2 id='questionTitle'> </h2>
        <ul id ='selectionList'> </ul>

        
        <button type="button" class = 'next'> Next </button>
      
    </div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use `var score = 0;` and instead of `console.log(true)` set `score ++;`. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Is `app.js` something we should be concerned about or is it just the jQuery that's already in the OP?

Answer (score 0):

A comment by @instead says that you can define a variable called `score` and if the answer is correct, you can increment score by 1 (using `score++`), otherwise decrement it by 1 (using `score--`). At the end, you can post the score using the `document.write()` method or referencing an HTML element and set its `innerHTML` element to be the total score.

Comment: You realize you can upovte and accept this answer if it helps you.